# Reset value to null in primefaces autocomplete event

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have an autocomplete event that fires correctly once a value is selected. I want another event to fire once I erase the value in the textbox and reset the value to null. I was thinking of using the onChange attribute but I was having issues so I reverted back to my original code.

```xhtml
<p:autoComplete id="deviceAuto" dropdown="true" scrollHeight="250" 
                value="#{summaryReportController.device.nickname}" 
                forceSelection="true" 
                completeMethod="#{summaryReportController.deviceComplete}">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" 
        listener="#{summaryReportController.handleDeviceSelect}" 
        update="printThis" />  
</p:autoComplete>
```

```java
public void handleDeviceSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    String deviceSelect = event.getComponent().getId();
    if (deviceSelect.equalsIgnoreCase("deviceAuto")) {
        Device selectedDevice = deviceMgr.getDevicebyNickname(device.getNickname());
        setDevice(selectedDevice);
    }
    updateInterface();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you modify the text content of the AutoComplete textfield, the search method (aka. completeMethod) will be called on the backing bean. You can reset the value to `null` there if you get an empty string.

**Backing Bean**

```
// insert getter and setter for the device property ...

/** Search for devices by name */
public List<String> deviceComplete(String search) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(search)) {
        setDevice(null);  // textfield was cleared, reset device value!
        return Collections.emptyList();
    } else {
        // search for devices ...
        return deviceNames;
    }
}
```

Note that I used [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) [StringUtils.isBlank(String)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29) to check if the string was null or did only contain whitespace characters.

**JSF View**

In your XHTML file you probably want to listen to any Ajax event to update your view -- or you figure out the event you need (blur, change, whatever) yourself:

```xhtml
<p:autoComplete ...>
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="..." update="..." />
    <p:ajax process="@this" update="..." />
</p:autocomplete>
```

I hope this helps.

---

An *alternative* could be something like a "clear" or "reset" button next to the search textfield to make it clear to the user that the value will be cleared.

Comment: Additional hint: Autocomplete supports the Ajax event "query" which is triggered on every text input.

Answer (score 4):

The default autoComplete `minQueryLength` attribute equals 1 and your search string will be updated when you deleting it until it has lenght of 1 character.

E.g.:
You entering 'foo' - and this string is provided to search method (updating after entering first character - minQueryLength = 1)

But when you delete search string - it is also updated until it will have length of 1.

Solution:
set attribute `minQueryLength="0"`

Or:

if you need bigger value add to your `autoCompleteMethod(String search)` condition:

```
if (search.length()<={your minQueryLength attribute} )   field = null;
```

Comment: This is not a solution with combination `dropdown="true"`, because on arrow click we expect some values to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I think it worths another view.

The problem with minQueryLenth = 0 or minQueryLenth = 1 is that it can return hundreds of options (and for sure the user won't read all of them to choose one). My solution was as follows.

First of all I need the input to be sent to the server as soon as the user select one of its values (in my use case the user is not allowed to go to next step in a wizard if this value is null or empty). So I put an ajax function triggered in the event of a selected value.

xhtml:

```
<p:autoComplete
    id="someId"
    value="#{myViewScopedBean.selectedValue}"
    ...
    ...
    minQueryLenth="5"
    onblur="autoCompleteLostFocus('someId', 'someCommand()')">

    <p:ajax
        event="itemSelect"
        listener="#{myViewScopedBean.newValueSelected}"
        process="@this"
        update="commandButtonGoToNextStep" />

</p:autoComplete>


<p:remoteCommand
    name="someCommand"
    actionListener="#{myViewScopedBean.setValueNull}"
    update="commandButtonGoToNextStep" />


<p:commandButton
    id="commandButtonGoToNextStep"
    ...
    ...
    disabled="#{myViewScopedBean.selectedValue == null}" />
```

If the user clean the text, I need to send that value to "myViewScopedBean" and update the component that allows the user to go to the next step. I solved that putting a javascript function that is called when the autocomplete lose focus.

javascript:

```
function autoCompleteLostFocus(autocompleteId, comand) {

    if ($("[id='" + autocompleteId + "_input']").val().trim() == "") {
        eval(comando);
    }

}
```

in myViewScopedBean:

```
public void setValueNull() {
    selectedValue = null;
}
```

I hope it helps. A lot of work, but the behaviour is exactly what I wanted. The reason for the javascript function is that it just send information to the servlet if the value is equals to "", otherwise it does nothing.

Comment: This is the proper solution IMHO. Problem with many items returned is no so big if maxResults on autoComplete is used. Problem is, that if you mark autoComplete with dropdown="true", then on arrow click one want to get some values, and in complete function we are not able to distinquish that input was emptied and user clicked on arrow...

Answer (score 0):

From a completely different angle...

Why do you have `summaryReportController.device.nickname` as a value in autoComplete?

I'd suggest you to use device as a value and specify

- var
- itemLabel
- itemValue
- converter

in your autocomplete, while your `completeMethod` will return list of devices filtered by nickname. Converter is implementation of `javax.faces.convert.Converter`.

See the POJO case in [PF Showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml).