# Capturing primefaces <p:autoComplete> change event (detect emptying)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, autocomplete

i got a question concerning an Primefaces autocomplete. Rigth now i am updating a field with the value of a property of the selected value in the autocomplete, like this:

This is in my xhtml:

```
<p:autoComplete
    value="#{trFitoModel.selectedProducte}"
    id="nomComercial"
    completeMethod="#{trFitoBacking.completeProducte}"
    var="producte" itemLabel="#{producte.nom}"
    itemValue="#{producte}" converter="#{ProducteFitoConverter}"
    forceSelection="true"
    onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect"
        listener="#{trFitoBacking.handleSelect}"
        update="text" global="false" />
    <f:validator validatorId="qea.validators.EmptyFieldValidator" />
    <f:attribute name="validationTitle" value=" NomComercial " />
</p:autoComplete>
</p:column>
<p:column>
    <h:outputLabel>#{msgI18N.trFito}</h:outputLabel>
    <h:outputText id="text"
        value="#{traFitoBacking.resgistre}">
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

And this is my Backing Bean:

```
 public void handleSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    ProducteFitosanitari p=(ProducteFitosanitari)event.getObject();
    setResgistre(Integer.toString(p.getNumRegistre()));
}
```

This works, but now I'm trying to update the outputText with id "text" with an empty String when the value of the autocomplete is empty.

How can I capture the event triggered when `p:autoComplete` is emptied?

Answer (score 35):

Primefaces autoComplete generates 2 events: "change" and "itemSelect", for 2 methods of changing its content: typing or selecting from dropdown list. So you need to register 2 [`p:ajax`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxifyAction.jsf) listeners:

```
<p:autoComplete ... >
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{bean.action}" process="@form"/> 
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.action}" process="@form"/> 
</p:autoComplete>
```

You'll need also 2nd server method signature:

```
public void action(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
```

for capturing 'change' event.

Instead of `event` you can use `onstart` attribute with JavaScript to run... More options for `p:ajax` you'll find in Primefaces Users Guide, section "AjaxBehavior".

Comment: There are also events for "itemUnselect", "query" and "moreText"

Comment: none of the events mentioned here reacts to text deletion (emptying) in PF 6.2

Comment: @Betlista Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9885518/5223047) for a possible solution.

Comment: @ltlBeBoy thanks, I saw that question (I have few comments there), I do not recall what exactly was a problem with p:ajax without event specified, maybe it just wasn't called...

Comment: I'm here half a year after and `<p:ajax event="change"` seems to work well, not sure where my testing went wrong previously... "itemUnselect" is valid for `multiple` option of autoComplete only...